# C# Script Error "Use of Unassigned variable 'line'?

Tags: c#, syntax-error, unassigned-variable

At this time, I am developing a script that will take employee information and display the info in a particular way IN this case, I attempted to use the `.ToString' method so keep the input displayed on the **same line** without **creating a new line** I know this is fairly simple, however i'm not fimilar with the error that was displayed. Any help would be appreciated.

*Sample of Code:*

```
Console.WriteLine("********* Prompt for Employee information and create first employee **********");


            Console.WriteLine("");



            Console.WriteLine("Enter the First name: ");

            Console.Write(line.ToString());

            if (line.Contains("x"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Enter the Last name: ");
                line2 = Console.ReadLine();

//Rest of Code Follows Same Flow...
```

Comment: How do you initialize `line`?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you declared line like this:

```
string line;
```

Try changing it to something like this:

```
string line = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no variable called `line` in your code. And even if it exists somewhere before the code segment you posted, it does not have a value. You may have declared it but never initialized it. So it doesn't hold a reference to an actual object.

If you want to print something to the console window in a single line, you can use `Console.Write()`